# Line in html change css

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a form with bootstrap:

```
<form class="form-inline">
          <div class="form-group barkodiK">
            <input type="text" class="form-control barkodi" placeholder="Barkodi">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group produktiK">
            <datalist id='produktet'></datalist>
            <input list="produktet" class="form-control produkti" onkeyup="merrProduktet(this)" placeholder="Produkti">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group pershkrimiK">
            <datalist id='pershkrimiProdukteve'></datalist>
            <input list="pershkrimiProdukteve" class="form-control pershkrimi" placeholder="Pershkrimi">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group cmimiK">
            <input type="text" class="form-control cmimi" readonly placeholder="Çmimi">
          </div>
        </form>
```

This form gives me this result:

[image]

But if i do this change in my editor lines it changes the structure also:

```
<form class="form-inline">
          <div class="form-group barkodiK">
            <input type="text" class="form-control barkodi" placeholder="Barkodi">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group produktiK">
            <datalist id='produktet'></datalist>
            <input list="produktet" class="form-control produkti" onkeyup="merrProduktet(this)" placeholder="Produkti">
          </div><div class="form-group pershkrimiK">
            <datalist id='pershkrimiProdukteve'></datalist>
            <input list="pershkrimiProdukteve" class="form-control pershkrimi" placeholder="Pershkrimi">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group cmimiK">
            <input type="text" class="form-control cmimi" readonly placeholder="Çmimi">
          </div>
        </form>
```

And i have this result:

[image]

I dont even know why this thing affects the CSS of HTML. Any help?

Comment: Check for CSS - paddings, margins, and also `.nth-child`s (if you have any).

Comment: This has to be something wrong with you CSS because there are no differences in the HTML. Could we possibly see some CSS?

Comment: Im using bootstrap

Comment: Only bootstrap? Any other CSS?

Comment: Yes only pure bootstrap

Comment: @Wowsk - there ***is*** a difference in the HTML, but it was hard to find because the OP did not call it out. Caleb Eby points it out in his answer.

Comment: i saw that difference but did not make the connection to the inline-display. well done @Caleb Eby

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the form inputs are displayed inline, the extra space you removed in the second file caused the inputs to move closer together:

```
</div><div class="form-group pershkrimiK">
```

This is what it should be if you want the space between the boxes:

```
</div>
<div class="form-group pershkrimiK">
```

When things are displayed inline, whitespace between/around elements is visible.

Comment: It makes sense now. Thanks for the answer.